# Runas command to read user details from a txt file

Tags: batch-file, runas

having an issue where a batch script of mine is changing time server REG Keys but requires admin privildges to do so, even if local user is admin.

My way around this i have found is using this line of code:

```
runas /noprofile /user:administrator\administrator "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Time Server.bat"
```

But this asks me for the admin password everytime, and i cant be doing this for 150+ users.

Can i get this command to read user details from a .txt file or .ini file?

Thank you in advanced.

OliV555

Comment: Are you in a domain environment? If so try pushing whatever your doing via a GPO.

Comment: Unfortunately not, we use OES (Novell) to access network drives. I was going to put this this batch file into the log on script of our clients.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible out of security reasons. I've spent a lot of time on this but at the end, I had to use a workaround:

Create a new task with the windows scheduler. In the interface select the admin user you want to run your script with and enter the password. Check the option to run the task with highest privileges. Let your task execute the batch file with all the code you want to run as admin. Don't enter any trigger to start your task automatically.

Now here's the trick:

To run your command with admin privileges simply execute

```
SCHTASKS /Run /TN <taskname>
```

If your local user is admin this will work straight on. Otherwise, you'll have to grant the user rights to start tasks.

**EDIT:** The scheduler will execute your batch file with system32 as working directory. So if you are using any relative paths in your script don't forget to adjust them or replace them with absolute paths.